# CSS Validator - Ruby

Tags: css, ruby, w3c-validation

I have the *css-validator.war* file provided by [W3C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web_Consortium) running locally on [JBoss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JBoss).

I have whipped together a very quick script to test it out:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

doc = '
* html {
    font-family: tahoma;
    background-color: black;
}
'

res = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://localhost:8080/css-validator/validator'),
  {'uri' => 'none', 'profile' => 'css2','usermedium' => 'all', 'type' => 'none', 'lang' => 'en', 'warning' => '1', 'output' => 'soap12', 'text' => doc})

response = res.body

puts response
```

When I browse to the validator in my web browser I can paste the CSS in fine and it validates fine, but when I run this script I get an error page saying:

> I/O Error:  You have sent an invalid
> request.

I have checked the parameters that I am passing and they seems fine.

Why would this be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a gem called w3c_validators which provides CSS, Markup, and Feeds validation.

```
gem install w3c_validators
```